# When to observe purnima fasting

Tags: fasting, purnima

Often the Purnima tithi is split between two days. On day 1 Purnima tithi beings and ends the second day.

Therefore there is confusion regarding when to observe the Purnima vrat. Some say that Purnima fasting should be observed on the day at which Purnima Tithi occurs at sunrise. On the other hand, some say that Purnima fasting should be observed on the day during which, Purnima tithi falls at night time when pooja of the Chandra is performed.

Which view is correct according to scriptures?